# compensate transactions in saga for failures

Tags: saga

i have a "compensatable transaction" tx that is part of a choreography saga and was wondering how to deal with compensation when a bug is introduced in the system. It is clear that if there is a business requirement not fullfiled by tx an *FailedEvent must be emitted in order to start the compensation action chain, but should an event be published as a result of a failure (null pointer, out of memory, and so) ? In my opinion this should be treated as a bug, compensation is not fired and shuould be fixed with a manuall process. This forces me to add some generic error event in a global exception handler. Not sure about it..
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of failures: Intermittent and business. For example for a money transfer a timeout or out-of-memory failure during deposit operation is intermittent. In the context of long running processes even a software bug that leads to a null pointer can be treated as intermittent.

Intermittent failures should be retried until it is resolved. It assumes that an operation is idempotent, but it is a table stake for such systems.

Business level failure, like "account id is invalid" shouldn't be retried. But these are very rare caused by a bug.

In your particular example, I would not emit "FailedEvent" to start compensation on unexpected failures (which should be treated as intermittent). I would nack the request into the incoming queue and expect a retry.

In many cases a business transaction that Saga implements is time-bound. For example, you are performing a payment at a supermarket. Then you have to ask for compensation for any failure as you can end up in an inconsistent state otherwise.

Note that queues are not a good fit for implementing Sagas. For example, they are not capable of long retries of a subset of messages. Also, it is very hard to make sense of what's going on in a choreography-based system, especially when something goes wrong.

I would recommend looking into [orchestration](https://temporal.io/) instead.